# what does it mean? configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_FUNCS(gettimeofday)

Tags: autotools, autoconf

I m learning the process of autotools, and when i run autoscan after introducing few functions example

```
 gettimeofday().
```

I am not able to associate the below statement into meaningful? can you explain what it tells?

```
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_FUNCS(gettimeofday)
```

Comment: Can you share your source code?  I'm guessing it means you (or some header you've included) is calling gettimeofday, but you haven't added the portability check to your configure.ac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`autoscan` is telling you that because `gettimeofday` is a potential portability issue, you should have a configure check for it.  So what you would need to do is add

```
AC_CHECK_FUNCS(gettimeofday)
```

to `configure.ac`, rerun `autoreconf`, and then decorate your C code with

```
#ifdef HAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY
```

That's the general process.

Personally, I think that `gettimeofday` specifically can be assumed to be present nowadays, and you can ignore this issue.  I don't think `autoscan` is widely used anymore (or at all).  Most projects just add configure checks when someone complains that something doesn't work on their system.  At some point you have to let go of ancient portability issues, but `autoscan` doesn't know what everyone's individual threshold is.